# tag:Microsoft EWS Connection error occasionally happens when I try to bind to email messages

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I have been using EWS exchange version 2015 for my code and it was working until recently, on several occasions, one of the several error messages appear

"The request failed. The remote name could not be resolved: 'outlook.office365.com'"

"The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

"The request failed. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

"The request failed. The operation has timed out"

when I am trying to bind to email messages. 
Currently the code sometimes work and at other times it doesn't. Just wondering does someone have a solution to this? Or is this just a issue on the office365 server side and I can do nothing about it?

```
exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2015);      
EmailMessage emailMsg = EmailMessage.Bind(exchangeService, item.Id);
```

Side Note:
I am absolutely sure that my credentials are correct and the domain name I have entered is correct as its hard coded into my application and I haven't edited it in years. With the same credentials I can log in to outlook.com successfully

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you change before this error appeared?

Comment: How frequent are the errors? Keep in mind that network errors are unavoidable in a networked environment, so you should expect and handle them.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Pretty frequent I'd say. I don't know if executing the program in China makes a difference.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Thanks for the welcoming. I did not change anything. The same executable has been working for years, but recently these errors pop up. Whats even more strange is that if I try to run the program another time it might work flawlessly again

Answer (score 0):

> "The request failed. The remote name could not be resolved: 'outlook.office365.com'"

Nothing to do with the Service (outside of any well documented outages) this is network connectivity or DNS resolution issue

> "The request failed. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Yep see this one a fair bit especially if your connection in more latent (I'm in Australia) it means for resilient code that every request for EWS you should wrap in Try Catch and retry at least once (you should also be doing this so you can process any throttling responses). Large attachment uploads can be a bit of pain if you have very low end network connections.

> "The request failed. The operation has timed out"

That can be service or the network, usually you would see that on a Search using FindItems. The default timeout in EWS Managed API is 90 seconds so you can adjust that up I've never seen that error on a Bind though so sounds like really poor network connectivity.

> "The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I would make sure you set the X-AnchorMailbox header as discussed in 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2018/06/16/best-practices-important-and-critical-headers-for-ews/ . This affect the routing of the request (and its always used by all client such as OWA and Outlook)

A good way of testing would be spin up a VM on Azure somewhere (you can choose different regions to test from) and run your code for a while there and test that against what you see locally to see if the errors correlate.

Comment: I would like to try out setting the X-AnchorMailbox header, however I am not sure which mailbox to set as the X-AnchorMailbox. 

In my code I am trying to access another mailbox with my own. I log in with my own credentials.  My mailbox was given folder permission to move rename and delete email messages. Is it the other mailbox that I was given folder permissions or my own that I need to set as the X-AnchorMailbox?